# Hyperbolic sinc function

Tags: functions, notation, terminology, special-functions, hyperbolic-functions

Cardinal sine function or sinc function is defined by:
\begin{equation}
\mathrm{sinc}x=\begin{cases}\frac{\sin x}{x}, & x \neq 0,\\
1, & x = 0,\end{cases}
\end{equation}

Is there any established name and notation for "hyperbolic sinc" function, where $\sin x$ is replaced by $\sinh x$?

Comment: I'm not able to find any such functions by the $\operatorname{Shi}$ seems to be it's antiderivative. ([source](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Shi.html))

Comment: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SinhcFunction.html

Comment: Note that (from [mathworld](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/SinhcFunction.html)), *"`sinhx/x` is not a cardinal function, the "analogy" with the sinc function is one of functional structure, not mathematical properties."*

Comment: @RemiCuingnet What is the relevance here of these two functions not sharing a (seemingly arbitrarily picked) mathematical property?

Answer (score 2):

Better late than never.  I would refer to it as the "hyperbolic sinc."

The notation I've seen used is sinhc x.

There's an article [Here](http://www.jstor.org/stable/10.4169/college.math.j.43.4.285?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents), which provides a geometric interpretation for it.

Full Reference:

The Hyperbolic Sine Cardinal and the Catenary, by 
Javier Sa ́nchez-Reyes, The College Mathematics Journal, Vol. 43, No. 4 (September 2012), pp. 285-290
http://dx.doi.org/10.4169/college.math.j.43.4.285